# How to highlight a line without a mouseover in chart?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I see simple example from demos:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/charts/Line.html

How to highlight a line without a mouseover in chart ( analog mouse over event of this line )?

Comment: By "dynamically" do you mean: highlight a line without a mouseover? Or are you just trying to achieve the same effect shown in the link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browse to that example and in the browser's javascript console write the following:

```
chart = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('.chart')[0];
serie = chart.series.items[0]; 
serie.highlightItem();
```

This is how it looks:

[image]